# how to edit captured images like whatsApp? means cropping image,draw lines ,adding text , emojis and filters on captured image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

Actually i have built custom camera & took picture, and drawn lines but i don't know how to add emojis on captured picture and make it movable And zoom.

actually i put all emojis in string type list,

```dart
 List<String> emojiUrls=[/*Urls of Emojis*/  ];
```

And Shown them into simple dialog box within button,

Main Body:

```dart
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new  Container(  
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
            image:FileImage(File(widget.imagePath)),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          )
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details){
            setState(() {
             RenderBox object=context.findRenderObject();
             Offset localPosition=object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition );
             points=new List.from(points)..add(localPosition);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details)=>points.add(null),
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: new Painter(points: points),
            size:Size.infinite ,
          ),
        ),
        foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(getIndexOfStickerId)
          )
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 40.0,color: Colors.red,),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
      )
    ],
   )
```